# Can't find my app on facebook insights?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-apps, facebook-social-plugins, facebook-insights

I'm running a site using social plugins, so I created a facebook app

then I want to use facebook insight to connect my website and app
(ps. I also add app_id or meta in header)

but I can't find the app I create in the connect list

[image: connect list pic]

does anyone has a clue what's going on??

Comment: Exact same problem here. My other apps are there in the drop-down, just like you. But my newly created one (the one I want to link) is not!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be a Facebook caching issue - the UI is simply not refreshing and providing the new app options. However you can still submit the request with the required app id manually. I used firebug to inject my new app id and name into the `<select>` element, and then submit the form as normal.

e.g:
1) Find the relevant input `<select>` element:
[image: UI and corresponding HTML]

2) Run this code in the Firebug (or equivalent) console, with the relevant [PLACEHOLDERS] replaced with your app id:

```
var fbidOptions = $$('select[name="fbid"]')[0];
var newOption = document.createElement('option');
newOption.setAttribute('value','fb:app_id,[PUT APP ID HERE]');
newOption.innerHTML = '[IT DOESNT REALLY MATTER, BUT PUT APP NAME HERE]';
fbidOptions.appendChild(newOption);
```

3) Select the newly injected option, and submit. The facebook servers will accept the app id as valid, leading me to believe its purely a UI caching issue.

[image]

Comment: @Tsung-JungWu Hahaha yep. I just submitted a bug report to FB. Feel free to add your repro case to it too!
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/199188366918767

Comment: I'm having a similar problem except none of my apps are showing up in the  "Link with" drop-down:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28435566/the-link-with-drop-down-for-adding-a-domain-to-insights-no-longer-lists-my-app/28461785#28461785   The hack worked for me.  Hopefully Facebook fixes this soon.