# The "Link With" drop-down for adding a domain to Insights no longer lists my apps

Tags: facebook, facebook-insights

I am trying to link a domain with an app in Facebook Insights.

https://www.facebook.com/insights/ => Domain Insights => Add Your Domain (Button)

Normally, I would see all of my applications in the "Link With" drop-down in the resulting dialog. However, as of yesterday, I only see my name: "Jason XXXXX (You)"

Anyone know what's going on with this?

Thanks in advance,
Jason

Answer (score -1):

I've been experiencing the same issue. Facebook previously supported page_ID as the on-site element for authorizing Domain Insights so my first thought was that they were moving to admin_ID as the only way ... but a co-worker was able to authorize via app_ID (through the drop down) so I'm not sure what's going on.

Comment: Glad to hear we're not alone. I was afraid that we ran into some hidden limit as we have a lot of domains using insights (500+).

Comment: Found a hack in the Related questions sidebar which worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15446031/cant-find-my-app-on-facebook-insights?rq=1  Not ideal, but, works for now until Facebook fixes this issue on their end.